# Android TV App - unable to select list item with remote

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-tv, leanback

Currently I am working on Android TV app.

I have used Android Lean back support library.

I have added one `ListView`, but I can not able to select any of the item from listView with real device's remote. However, I can able to select item of listView on my Android Virtual Device with the help of mouse.

Here is my sample code of listView:

```
customViewOrders = new CustomViewOrders(getActivity().getBaseContext(), arrayViewOrders);
lstViewOrder.setAdapter(customViewOrders);
```

Here, `arrayViewOrders` is my ArrayList which contains data received from JSON webservice.

Here is my JSON Response:

```
{
   "order":[
      {
         "0":"13829CF",
         "gen_id":"13829CF",
         "1":"17534CF",
         "2":"Complete",
         "ord_status":"Complete",
         "3":"Online Preview",
         "sta_name":"Online Preview",
         "4":"2015-10-27 00:00:00",
         "image":"cinereel",
         "placed_from":"web"
      }
   ]
}
```

I have also added following features in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.faketouch"
    android:required="true" />
```

So, my question is: **how to select anything** (i.e. list item, button) **in real device with the help of remote?**

Comment: Please add JSON response you are getting..

Comment: @Kamal - I have added JSON response.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I got the solution after lots of R&D.

Here is the my solution for directional navigation using Android TV remote.

Firstly, you have to keep focus of any one of items (i.e. `Button`, `TextView`, etc.) as below.

And also, you have to apply its `nextFocusDown`, `nextFocusLeft`, `nextFocusRight` & `nextFocusUp` properties, so that it will fire its relevant event when you click TV remote navigation buttons.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSignout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvUserName"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivUser"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:nextFocusRight="@+id/ivUser" <!-- On click of right arrow button, focus will be move to ivUser id -->
    android:nextFocusUp="@+id/tvUserName" <!-- On click of up arrow button, focus will be move to tvUserName id -->
    android:text="@string/signout"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium">

    <requestFocus></requestFocus>

</Button>
```

For more information, you can refer to:

1. [Android User Interface Design: The Basics of Control Focus Order](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-the-basics-of-control-focus-order--mobile-8013),
2. [Creating TV Navigation](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/tv/start/navigation.html).