# How can I allow a remote to move focus from keyboard to button on the screen?

Tags: android, android-tv

I have an android TV app that is accepting a password and outside of the keyboard I have a button that will show the password. I can't move from the keyboard to the show password button without physically backing out of the editText, is it possible to make it so the keyboard can always be shown and I can move directly from keyboard to the button for focus?

Answer (score 0):

What you needed is to [create TV navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/navigation) it will help you understand the minimum requirements for creating effective TV app navigation scheme and how to apply those requirements to your app, see also [Provide clear focus and selection](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/navigation#focus-selection).

Additional reference:
[Android User Interface Design: The Basics of Control Focus Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34720761/android-tv-app-unable-to-select-list-item-with-remote) and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34720761/android-tv-app-unable-to-select-list-item-with-remote)